# How to rename an AWS API Gateway API instance?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

In AWS API Gateway, is it possible to rename an API instance somehow?

I don't see the option on the UI, but maybe it's possible by using some API call.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes it's available in the API or CLI.

In the API you use a PATCH request on the 'name' field. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/rest-api/

In the CLI, see docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-rest-api.html

The PATCH op is 'replace' and the path would be '/name'

Edit: Thanks @Canotto90 for the example

`aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id IDOfTheAPIThatNeedsTobeUpdated --patch-operations op=replace,path=/name,value=NewName`

Comment: Thanks! Running: `aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id miApiId --patch-operations op=replace,path=/name,value=testName` worked.

Comment: Thank you @canotto90. Saved me some time concocting that command.

Comment: Why it's not available in the UI?

Answer (score 22):

Here is how you can get the list of APIs and their IDs:

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis
```

Use the Id to update name of API as mentioned by [Canotto90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401475/canotto90) above:

```
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id IDOfTheAPIThatNeedsTobeUpdated --patch-operations op=replace,path=/name,value=NewName
```

Answer (score 16):

It turns out, there is now a way to rename the API!

Under the Amazon API Gateway service, select `APIs`. You will see the list of your APIs.

[image: List of APIs]

Now, click the little cog wheel in the top right corner of the API that you wish to rename...

[image: cog wheel]

Simply change the name, hit save, and you're good!

[image: editing UI]

Comment: Thank god they allowed us to change it in the console

Answer (score 12):

From https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway -> Select API by Name -> Settings -> General Settings -> Name

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but people may still need an answer as I just did.

Amazon's AWS UI isn't always clear.  There is no "Rename" function to change the name of an existing API.  However, it can be done by cloning your existing API.

To rename your API, click the "Create API" button and select "Clone from existing API".  This will allow you to give it a new name.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the console allows you to edit the name via the API settings: [see where in console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVv9h.png)